# Codeigniter - how to get data from a model query into controller function

Tags: codeigniter, model

I'm having trouble understanding how to get data (single row) from a model query into a controller function in codeigniter. I've searched the stack overflow posts, but no luck. I have a query in a model like this:

```
function login($email, $sha1Pass) {
    $loginArray = array('email' => $email, 'pw' => $sha1Pass);
    $this->db->select('lid, email, pw');
    $this->db->from('login');
    $this->db->where($loginArray);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->row();
}
```

There will only be 1 returned row `[lid, email, pw]`

I then have a controller that calls this model query.

```
$report['row'] = $this->LoginCheck->login($email, $encp);
```

What I need is 2 fields from the database from the row and assign them to a variable like this:

```
$lid = $report['lid'];
$email = $report['email'];
```

`lid` and `email` are the fields from the database.

Answer (score 1):

You can access them like:

```
$lid = $report['row']->lid;
$email = $report['row']->email;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Login_model

public function auth($nm,$pwd)
{
    $this->db->select('uname,password');
    $q1=$this->db->get_where('user_details',array('uname'=>$nm,'password'=>$pwd));
    return $q1->row();
}

//you can call this method from controller like

$data['query']=$this->Log_Model->auth($unm,$pswd);

//And you can create session variable like,

$this->session->set_userdata('uname',$data['query']->uname);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you view set this

```
$lid = $report['lid'];
$email = $report['email'];
```

Then add some on model to get query as

```
function login($email, $sha1Pass) {
$loginArray = array('email' => $email, 'pw' => $sha1Pass);
$this->db->select('lid, email, pw');
$this->db->from('login');
$this->db->where($loginArray);
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->row_array();
}
```

just set `row()` to `row_array()`

Answer (score 0):

```
  $data = array(
        'username' => $_POST['fullname'],
        'useremail' => $_POST['email'],
        'social_login_id' => $_POST['bq_user_id'],
        'social_login_type' => $loginType,
        'login_status' => 'online',
        'is_active' =>1,
    );
    $this->db->insert($this->TABLE, $data);
```

Comment: Hi, This may answer the question, please provide some explanation of your code.